# Dialog inside dialog not DialogReturn-ing properly

Tags: front-end, notebooks

How can I prevent the DialogInput from failing (or returning early) as soon as I close the "Close this" dialog?

```
DialogInput@Button["Click this", CreateDialog["Close this" ]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Would that help?

```
DialogInput@
 Column[{Button["Click this", 
    CreateDialog["Close this",NotebookEventActions -> {}]],
   Button["Done", DialogReturn["done"]]
   }]
```

I think the outer dialog won't return as long as the inner dialog doesn't call `DialogReturn` (it could do something else, though). `DialogReturn[$Failed]` is somehow automatigally inserted for some event actions when calling  `CreateDialog`, although `Options[CreateDialog,NotebookEventActions]` returns `{NotebookEventActions -> None}`. The inserted event actions can be seen e.g. with this:

```
CreateDialog[
 Dynamic@Column@
   CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookEventActions]]
```

Comment: +1 Yeah, it helped, thanks! Now I scrapped a solution that haven't tested intensely but I'm posting it as a self answer

Answer (score 4):

```
nestedDialog[] := Module[{tag = True},
   Unprotect[DialogReturn];
   DialogReturn[i_] /; tag := 
    Internal`InheritedBlock[{System`FEDump`$DialogDone},
         Unprotect[DialogReturn];
         DialogReturn[j_] /; tag =.;
         System`FEDump`$DialogDone /: 
      HoldPattern[System`FEDump`$DialogDone = True] = True;
         DialogReturn[i];
         Protect[DialogReturn];
         System`FEDump`$DialogDone /: 
      HoldPattern[System`FEDump`$DialogDone = True] =.;
     ];
   Protect[DialogReturn];
   ];
```

Use: just call `nestedDialog[]` before creating new nested dialogs. It makes sense to make the nested dialogs modal because the `DialogInput` won't return until as many `DialogReturns`have been run as `nestedDialog[]`s have been run (plus one)

```
DialogInput@{Button["Click this", nestedDialog[]; 
   CreateDialog["Close this", Modal -> True]], 
  DefaultButton[DialogReturn["alskjl"]]}
```

I tested this in Mathematica 8.0.4, W7x64.
Quoted from @AlbertRetey's comment. *"I have now tested your code with Mathematica 6.0.2,7.0.1 and 8.0.4 on both Windows 7 and Linux (CentOS) and at least the simple example seems to work alright with any of them"*

Comment: +1, unlike my suggestion this really makes possible to use nested modal dialogs, which I couldn't get to work up to now. As you are using nondocumented internal functions, I'd suggest to add a note with which version you have tested this...

Comment: I have now tested your code with Mathematica 6.0.2,7.0.1 and 8.0.4 on both Windows 7 and Linux (CentOS) and at least the simple example seems to work alright with any of them. I would conclude what you are using seems to be fairly stable amongs the various versions. Maybe you want to add that to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
DialogInput[Button["Click this",
  CreateDialog["Close this", NotebookEventActions -> {"WindowClose" :> DialogReturn[]}]]]
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work... I'm on 8.0.0 right now, and that prevents the failed return but doesn't prevent the early return. Changes $Failed to Null

Comment: @Rojo I missed the bit where you wanted to keep the underlying window.